# Comparison of two select queries in one query

Tags: sql, select, google-bigquery

I am trying to find out the results of these two queries(count), find the difference, output 1 if it is not equal, otherwise output 0. So I wanted a single query which gives me 1 if there is a difference, 0 if there is no difference.

my select firstquery

```
select sum (mass) as firstquerycount from
 (
  SELECT safe_cast(sum(column1) as int) as mass,'dummy' FROM `dataset.table1` WHERE DATE(dateTime) = current_date()-1
union all
  SELECT safe_cast(sum(anothercol) as int) as mass,'dummy' FROM `dataset.table2` WHERE DATE(dateTime) =
  current_date() -1
union all
SELECT safe_cast(sum(column3) as int) as mass,'dummy' FROM `dataset.table3`  WHERE DATE(dateTime) = current_date()-1
 ) x
```

my secondquery

```
SELECT ifnull(safe_cast(sum(colmass) as int),0) as secondquerycount FROM `dataset1.table4`
WHERE DATE(timeInterval) = (current_date -1)
and country in (SELECT ctry FROM `dataset2.table5` WHERE DATE(bqInsertTime) = current_date()  and county='Utopia' and contactType in ('call','sms','outlook') )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both of these have a single row result set, you can cross-join them together and do your math:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN firstquerycount = secondquerycount THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as result
FROM 
   (
      select sum (mass) as firstquerycount from
      (
        SELECT safe_cast(sum(column1) as int) as mass,'dummy' FROM `dataset.table1` WHERE DATE(dateTime) = current_date()-1
        union all
        SELECT safe_cast(sum(anothercol) as int) as mass,'dummy' FROM `dataset.table2` WHERE DATE(dateTime) =
        current_date() -1
        union all
        SELECT safe_cast(sum(column3) as int) as mass,'dummy' FROM `dataset.table3`  WHERE DATE(dateTime) = current_date()-1
      ) x
   ) dt1,
   (
      SELECT ifnull(safe_cast(sum(colmass) as int),0) as secondquerycount FROM `dataset1.table4`
      WHERE DATE(timeInterval) = (current_date -1)
      and country in (SELECT ctry FROM `dataset2.table5` WHERE DATE(bqInsertTime) = current_date()  and county='Utopia' and contactType in ('call','sms','outlook') )
   ) dt2

   )
```